# Fedora: Application Container Cannot establish connection to DB Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose, psycopg2

I am having trouble connecting to a db container from the application container on a Fedora Host. I have verified being able to connect to the database using the same credentials via the psql command line interface. Using the same information in my application does not work.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    postgrestest:
        build: ./vrs
        command: python3 app.py
        volumes:
            - ./vrs/:/appuser/
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - db
    
    db:
        image: postgres:12-alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER={{user}}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD={{password}}
            - POSTGRES_DB=sharepointvrs

volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

This is the code used to connect to the container, from within the application container:

```py
dbconfig = environment["database"]


try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=dbconfig["dbname"], #sharepointvrs
        user=dbconfig["user"],
        password=dbconfig["password"],
        host=dbconfig["host"], # tried 0.0.0.0, localhost, and IP address obtained from docker inspect
        port=dbconfig["port"] # 5432
    )
    connection.autocommit = True
except:
    print("Database initialization failed.")
```

I've tried both using localhost and using the IP obtained from running a docker inspect:

[image]

Comment: Is the database actually started up when you attempt to connect?  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that describes the host names available to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to firewall interface policies configured by the docker installation on Fedora.

Docker must be added to the trusted zone before it gets installed.

More information [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting your solution.  What host did you set in your app in the end?

Answer (score 1):

> `# tried 0.0.0.0, localhost, and IP address obtained from docker inspect`

In your app's config, set the database host to `'db'`

That exists as a DNS alias, available in the other containers, based on what you set the service name to in your compose file:

```
services:
  db:
    # ...
```

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: the container is able to resolve the host but the connection is still not working, any other suggestions